# General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value, how do i store user_id when signed in using different guard

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have two different types of guards the default users and a guard called customer. I am trying to get the customers to follow the users but i am getting the error `General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value` . I know why but i don't know how to fix the issue. If i am signed using customer guard how do i grab the user_id from the user page when i am not signed in using the default user guard.

**Controller:**

```
public function follow(User $user, $slug) {
   $user = User::where('slug', $slug)->first();

   $customer = Auth::guard('customer')->user();
   $customer->follow($user);

   return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'You are now following user');

}

public function unfollow(User $user, $slug){
    $merchant = User::where('slug', $slug)->first();

    $customer = Auth::guard('customer')->user();
    $customer->unfollow($merchant);

    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'You have unfollowed merchant');
}
```

**View:**

```
@if(Auth::guard('customer')->user())
   @if(Auth::guard('customer')->user()->isfollowing($user))
      <a href="{{ url('account/'.$user->slug.'/unfollow') }}" class="btn btn-danger">Unfollow</a>
   @else
      <a href="{{ url('account/'.$user->slug.'/follow') }}" class="btn btn-success">Follow</a>
   @endif
@endif
```

Comment: Can you add the method that throw the error. I assume either `$customer->follow()` or`$customer->unfollow()`.

Comment: @Remul i am using a package called https://github.com/overtrue/laravel-follow?ref=madewithlaravel.com